# How to know if it's a child taxonomy?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm in need to know if the current taxonomy is child or parent. How can i achieve this?

I need it for the condition in if statement. I need to know

```
if(this is child taxonomy){

}
```

Anybody knows how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using this piece of code, found in the WordPress support articles and which you can see [here.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/if-current-taxonomy-has-child-andor-parent)

Comment: please do not post link-only answers, see [how to answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors).

```
$ancestors = get_ancestors( 4, 'category' );
// var_dump($ancestors); // debugging
if (!empty($ancestors)) {
  // category 4 is a child of some other category
} else {
  // category 4 is not a child. It is "top-level" in the hierarchy.
}
```